# How do I add groups to a ListView?

Tags: vba, listview, ms-access, activex

As a noob to ActiveX controls, I managed to get a `ListView` (v6) up and running on my MS-Access 2019 form.

I am unfamiliar and clumsy with the way to implement it, and I do not really know what documentation to use (getting confused with the many options, .NET CORE, .NET Framework 4.8 etc. etc.). Grateful if someone could point me to the resources on the web!

Now, I'd like to add groups to the `ListView`, but can't figure out how to do that. I found examples that were clearly not VBA and tried to translate these, but failed.

<strike>Same goes for making the font a bit larger.</strike>

My code to set up and fill the `ListView` with example data:

```
Dim oListView As ListView 

Private Sub Form_Load()

  Dim oListItem As ListItem
  Dim n As Integer

  Set oListView = Me.lvwTest.Object
  oListView.Font.Size = 12

  For n = 1 To 4

    Set oListItem = oListView.ListItems.Add(, "a" & n, n)
    oListItem.ListSubItems.Add, , "Foo " & n
    oListItem.ListSubItems.Add, , "Bar " & n

  Next

End Sub
```

**Edit**

Why `ListView`:

I have a list of services, these are linked to a specific date, like

```
------------------------------------------
01/28/2020                            [-]
------------------------------------------ 
double room                    1   58.00 €
breakfast                      2   16.00 €
------------------------------------------
01/29/2020                            [-]
------------------------------------------
double room - tuesday special  1   52.00 €
breakfast                      2   16.00 €
dinner                         2   26.00 €
foo                            2   12.00 €
bar                            1    4.60 €
------------------------------------------
01/30/2020 etc. etc.                  [-]
------------------------------------------
```

`ListView` is able to right-align the € column and - as I thought - add groups (dates). I'd like to expand/hide the rows of each group by a click on the group header.

Comment: You're using VBA/ActiveX, a tech from ~1998. Everything you read about .NET, .NET Core, .NET Framework, Windows Forms, or WPF, is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Access, but look into "access master-detail forms" and subforms.

Comment: I don't think you have many other options.

Comment: *Why* do you want to use ListView? You need to consider that as an ActiveX control it is very problematic to use due to licensing issues, limited to 32-bit, sensitive to versioning and few more problems. Maybe you should try and state what you are trying to do and we can suggest a solution that doesn't require an obsolete ActiveX control.

Comment: A ListView can't do groups. A **TreeView** has collapsible groups, but doesn't have multiple columns. I'd say you need a datasheet for this.

Comment: @Andre seems a "modern" ListView **can** have groups, just the VBA/Access one doesn't, a shame. Yes, already started to make a solution with a continuous subform

Answer (score 1):

For grouping forget ListView and switch to MSHFlexGrid.
Notice the "**H**"...stands for Hierarchical and its probably the most powerful ActiveX control ever.
Check here :http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?412201-Is-there-a-control-that-is-a-combination-between-TreeView-and-ListView

Comment: thanks, but it seems it is "dead" https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/037d3899-8a10-45fc-9673-5dddfce3924b/demise-of-hierarchical-flex-grid-?forum=vbide

Comment: Pretty much nothing is dead unless you are using 64bit Access...The Control works fine and its functionality is outstanding .

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my question from what I learned from comments and research. Feel free to add to this answer.

**The `ListView`-Control in MS-Access does not support grouping its `ListItems`.**

I turned to having a *continuous subform* instead of a `ListView`, formatting group-headers with *conditional formatting*. An extra textbox `txtHeader` indicates if a row is to be formatted as group-header.
If so, *format conditioning* will set a highlighting background-color on an empty and unbound textbox that is behind all other controls covering all of the detail section of the subform.
Doesn't have the clean look of a nicely grouped `ListView`, but doesn't bring the possible hassle of ActiveX-controls either.

As John suggested in comments, `MSHFlexGrid` is an ActiveX-Control that supports grouping. Unfortunately it isn't available on 64bit.